# Как по нормальному реализовать систему предметов?

Tags: unity3d

Я решил сделать 4 класса (scriptable object) которые обозначают тип предмета(оружие, ресурс, инструмент и т.п.) и решил сделать класс Items с 4 листами, которые хранят предметы. Потом понял что способ странный и много минусов

Потом подумал про interface, но я туда максимум запихну sprite, name, amount, maxAmount. А как например если предмет оружие, то в scriptable object указывало Damage, firerate и т.п.

И бываю предметы которые не только могут быть инструментом, но и оружием. У предмета может быть анимация, как оно работает и т.п.

Я ничего по этому не нашел, что делать?